# CachedFileUpdater doesn't work in OneDrive app on mobile?

Tags: win-universal-app, onedrive, windows-10-mobile

There is a [Cached File Updater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.provider.cachedfileupdater.aspx) contract which allows apps like OneDrive or DropBox to keep files in sync with remote repository when users change them though file pickers. It works roughly like this:

- User gets a file using FileOpenPicker.
- User changes file.
- The source app gets notification that file is changed and uploads new file to backing storage.

However, while in official DropBox app this scenario works perfectly, in OneDrive app it doesn't. I'm getting UnauthorizedAccessException when try to get stream for read from a file. I understand some people actually able to change a file, but it doesn't get uploaded because only local copy changes.

So CachedFileUpdater is not implemented in OneDrive app? And if it's not, is it known issue and is there any workarounds for this?