# Issues when saving files to OneDrive on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: onedrive, windows-10-mobile

I’m working on an application where you should be able to open and save files, similar to “Notepad”. It’s a universal application that should work both on computers and mobiles.

The application works fine on computers. It also works fine on mobile if I save or open files locally or on Dropbox.

But if I open a file on OneDrive (via the file picker), and then try to save an exception is thrown: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

If I select “Save as” on OneDrive it works. But every time I select Save after this a new instance of the file is created (I get “file 1”, “file 2”, “file 3” and so on).

I have only tested this on my phone. I might have a bug on my application, but since it works on DropBox I don’t think so. Is this a known issue with OneDrive? Or might I just have some local issues? I’m using Windows 10 Mobile 10.10586.420 and OneDrive 17.11.

Here is some code to illustrate the problem:

```
<Page
     x:Class="BasicEditor.MainPage"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:local="using:BasicEditor"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     mc:Ignorable="d">

 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="40">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="Open"
      Click="OpenButton_Click" />
    <Button Content="Save"
      Click="SaveButton_Click" />
    <Button Content="Save as"
      Click="SaveAsButton_Click" />
   </StackPanel>

  <TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TextEditor"
      TextWrapping="Wrap" />
  </Grid>
 </Page>





using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using Windows.Storage;
 using Windows.Storage.AccessCache;
 using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
 using Windows.UI.Popups;
 using Windows.UI.Xaml;
 using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;



// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace BasicEditor
 {



 /// <summary>
  /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
  /// </summary>
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
     {
         public MainPage()
         {
             this.InitializeComponent();
         }

  string MruToken;

  private async void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
     try
     {
      string fileContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
      TextEditor.Text = fileContent;

      string token = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(file, "");
      MruToken = token;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"Open-Error: {ex.Message}");

     var dialog = new MessageDialog($"Open-Error: {ex.Message}");
      await dialog.ShowAsync();
     }
    }
   }



  private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    try
    {
     var file = await StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync(MruToken);

    string fileContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, TextEditor.Text);

    var dialog = new MessageDialog($"Saved successfully");
     await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"Save-Error: {ex.Message}");

    var dialog = new MessageDialog($"Save-Error: {ex.Message}");
     await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }

  }



  private async void SaveAsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Document";
    StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
     try
     {
      await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, TextEditor.Text);

     string token = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(file, "");
      MruToken = token;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"SaveAs-Error: {ex.Message}");

     var dialog = new MessageDialog($"SaveAs-Error: {ex.Message}");
      await dialog.ShowAsync();
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

A beta of my app is available here: https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NBLGGH3MFM3

Another app with exactly the behavior when OneDrive is used is NotepadX.

Comment: I [stumbled on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530356/cachedfileupdater-doesnt-work-in-onedrive-app-on-mobile) myself too. Looks like OneDrive app doesn't properly implement CachedFileUpdater, which is necessary for saving file back to OneDrive. So you can either settle with copying this file to local cash and then making user save it to OneDrive manually, or implement this functionality with OneDrive api and not the app.

Comment: Oh no, I hope that gets resolved soon :-(. I have noticed that it seems to work as expected in Office, but it looks like Office uses the file picker as well. Strange…